# Ordenar list de objetos python

Tags: python, django, lista

Estoy tratando de ordenar una lista de objetos Jugador en Django1.10 y Python 3.5. Pero me es imposible y no logro dar con el error.

La clase del objeto es la sigueinte

```
class Jugador(models.Model):

#Otras propiedades
rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)

def __cmp__(self, other):
    if self.rating < other.rating:
        rst = -1
    elif self.rating > other.rating:
        rst = 1
    else:
        rst = 0

    return rst
```

Para ordenar la lista, tras calcular el rating de cada jugador, guardo la propiedad y la añado a una lista, la cuál me gustaría que estuviera ordenada por la propiedad rating.

```
def ratingCalculte(jugadores, user, temporada):
result = []
#Calculando rating
.....
.....

    jugador.rating = rating
    jugador.save()
    result.append(jugador)

sorted(result)

return result
```

La excepción es:

> ```
> unorderable types: Jugador() < Jugador()
> ```

he probado de todo, y no se que puede hacer. Y anteriormente en una versión beta de la apliación ordenaba de esta misma forma y no había ningún problema.

Comment: Hola kyle, creo que todas esas asignaciones son demasiadas para el error del que hablas y pueden abrumar un poco al leerlo. Puedes dejar solo las imprescindibles como `rating`? Un saludo

Comment: Hecho! Gracias por el consejo lois6b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás usando Python3, definir el método **Cmp** no sirve para hacer "sorteable" el objeto, corresponde definir con mayor precisión las comparaciones que deben hacerse, para un simple sort bastaría con definir el método `__lt__()` o "less than".

Comment: En efecto, eso mismo era. Muchas gracias.